# Statistical landscape

Tags: bayesian, frequentist, philosophical

Has anyone written a brief survey of the various approaches to statistics? To a first approximation you have frequentist and Bayesian statistics. But when you look closer you also have other approaches like likelihoodist and empirical Bayes. And then you have subdivisions within groups such as subjective Bayes objective Bayes within Bayesian statistics etc.

A survey article would be good. It would be even better if it included a diagram.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one I found via a Google Image search, but maybe it's *too* brief, and the diagram too simple: http://labstats.net/articles/overview.html

Comment: Thanks. That's a nice article. It's a start at what I have in mind, but as you say it's very brief.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a longer article. No diagram and isn't exactly a survey, more, as the abstract puts it, of 'an idiosyncratic walk through some of these issues':

M. J. Bayarri and J. O. Berger (2004). ["The Interplay of Bayesian and Frequentist Analysis"](http://www.jstor.org/stable/4144373). *Statistical Science* **19** (1):58-80.

(access requires a JSTOR subscription)

Comment: You can get this article for free (although may be a slightly different version) here  http://www.isds.duke.edu/~berger/papers/interplay.pdf .  Okay to give a "free" link, because its on James Berger's Website.

Comment: I look forward to reading that one. Jim Berger has deep insights.